# AutoHotKey not finding image on a window

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I recently discovered AutoHotKey, this scripting language seemed to be amazing !

Unfortunately, I can't manage to make my script find an image on a window (BlueStacks in my case).
Can someone please help me, my script is :

```
CoordMode, Pixel, screen
CoordMode, Mouse, screen

*ESC::ExitApp

ImgFound := false

while(ImgFound = false)
{
  ImageSearch, ButtonX, ButtonY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, *50 C:\Users\...\Documents\...\test.png
  if (ErrorLevel = 2)
  {
      MsgBox Could not execute script.
      ExitApp
  }
  else if (ErrorLevel = 1)
  {
    ImgFound := false
  }
  else
  {
      MsgBox Found.
      click, %ButtonX%, %ButtonY%
      ImgFound := true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop is unreachable code.
The code execution stops when the first hotkey label is encountered. This is called the [Auto-execute Section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto).

Move your hotkey definition to be at the very bottom.
(All hotkeys always defined by hotkeys labels get always created regardless of being in the auto-execute section or not)